# Visual Studio Indent does weird things

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

This issue i'm having is a big mystery for now for days , i tried searching the internet but i can't find an explanation.

Before the issue occured my code looked like this:
[image: Good layout]

But now everytime i ty to add something it looks like this[image]

VS does this after i press enter between {}. So that my issue and i can't figure it out.. Did i hit a keycombo , did devexpress or resharper broke it , I don't know. So does anybody have an idea how to fix this

Comment: That looks like the behavior you get when you have a syntax error in the file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming your tab indexes have changed, you can change them back following these steps:

- Open Tools / Options:

[image]

- Select Text Editor / Your Language / Tabs:

[image]

You may need to format the file for the tabs to re-adjust again :-)

Comment: Ha, I always feel lucky when I press the wrong key combo and I get informed that there is no action for that combination! No worries!